# Struggling to Create a Simple Copy/Paste Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to learn on my own by watching YouTube videos and reading forums, but I'm still struggling and...I'm a little embarrassed because it seems so simple. I'm hoping any answers/suggestion from you will help me in the future.

I have two sheets "**Bishop**" and "**Log**". I want to copy two specific cells (**K11** and **K12**) from "**Bishop**", which are vertically aligned, and paste them horizontally in the sheet "**Log**" at **C4** and **D4**, respectively, without any formatting or formulas being copied over.

Each time I press a button (I've already made and attached a script to) I want it to paste in those two cells, and then move down to the next empty row (so C4,D4 to C5,D5, C6,D6...and so on).

I never intended on getting someone to finish my script for me, but I'm getting confused by the examples I've found in my research. Here's my script so far (after deleting many dysfunctional versions)

```
function Logger(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bishop = ss.getSheetByName('Bishop');
  var log = ss.getSheetByName('Log');

}
```

I tried to copy and modify code examples from YouTube videos and articles, but I think my by modifying them I'm just making a mess.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.
Dustin

EDIT
After some tinkering and reading some more, I now have a pretty nifty script that copies data in to where I want it! However, my next goal is to learn how to move down one row each time I run the script, so it creates an actual list, or log. "InputData" and "PasteRange" are named ranges on my source sheet and destination sheet, respectively. Here's my code so far:

```
function Logger(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bishop = ss.getSheetByName('Bishop');
  var log = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
 
ss.getRange("InputData").copyTo(log.getRange("PasteRange"),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far your script has gotten to the point of creating 2 variables that reference the Bishop and Log sheets.

Next, you'll need to select the specific ranges in those sheets. To get a range in a sheet, use the `getRange` method, which has a few variations on what inputs it takes. For example:

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
```

Once you have references to the ranges, you can use the `getValue` or `getValues` method to extract the values inside a range, and then use the `setValue` or `setValues` method to overwrite new data into an existing range. For example:

```
var myValues = range1.getValues();
range2.setValues(myValues);
```

If you haven't seen [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) page before, take a look; it's probably the most helpful single webpage for writing sheet scripts.

(Also, I won't write the code for you; Stackoverflow is about specific questions and answers, not about figuratively doing your homework, though the lines are blurry at times. But feel free to keep asking questions!)

Comment: Thank you for that link/resource. I spent some time going over it. There's so much in there. Perhaps there's a better way, but I settled on "copyTo" and based my code on the example on that page. It worked like a charm! My next goal is to figure out what methods I should use to move down one row each time it copies the data, instead of just copying over it. Could you point me in the right direction and I'll work on it some more? I edited my OP with updated code.

Comment: You'll want to be nice and clear about what you want to do: What exactly does "move down one row each time it copies the data" mean? What is it that is moving down one row? Regardless, perhaps insertRowAfter will be helpful.

Comment: I suppose, to be exact, I want to find the last row that has data in it, and paste in the row below it. So each time it does it, it will continuously build a longer and longer list of copied data.

Comment: getLastRow seems to be what I need, apparently.

Comment: Ah, now I know what you mean. Yes, I agree with getLastRow; I've never seen that one before and it looks useful. I think you'd still want insertRowAfter too, at least if you're concerned about ever hitting the existing row limit.